# PHP file_get_contents return error

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm wondering if it's possible to have an if statement something like this:

```
if file_get_contents() returns error code xxx OR xxx
    die();
```

I'm not sure how to check if `file_get_contents()` returns an error.

Answer (score 8):

It seems you are looking to get the HTTP status code.  In that case, you need to read it from here:

```
$http_response_header
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Otherwise, if you want the generic error, follow deceze's instructions.

Answer (score 5):

> http://php.net/file_get_contents
>
> The function returns the read data or FALSE on failure.

It either works or it doesn't, as such:

```
$file = file_get_contents(...);
if ($file === false) {
    die();
}
```

---

PS: Of course, in the above answer I expect you use `file_get_contents` to get the contents of a local file. If you're trying to get the HTTP status code of a remote URL, I'd suggest you use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) or similar specialized HTTP libraries and parse the response headers.

Comment: Well I'm trying to get a remote JSON file, but I assume the above codes will still work, I don't need to get a specific code, like you said, it either works or it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

As the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) state, `file_get_contents()` will return `false` on all errors, so all you can do is

```
if ($content=file_get_contents($filename)===false) die("Error reading file $filename");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call it that way:

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://site.com/that.php");
if ($data !== FALSE) {
   // analyze data
}
```